# Refactoring a loop in Python

Tags: python, refactoring

I know this is not good coding and I'm looking to improve it. I want to get the first name by default if no name is supplied. My hack still enters the for loop and if it would be a big one it would be innefficient. But if I do all the attributions that I'm doing in the for loop's inside if, again, in the outside if, I would duplicate code. And I wouldn't use a function just to set attributes so I'm not sure how to proceed here.

```
    if not name:
        name = self.data['big_list'][0]['name']

    for i in range(len(self.data['big_list'])):
        if self.data['big_list'][i]['name'] == name:
            self.name = name
            self.address = self.data['big_list'][i]['address']
            ...
            return
```

Comment: this whole data structure looks awful. what are you trying to achieve? why do you operate on Dict[List[Dict] ? what if you simply try IF NOT NAME ... ELSE doForLoopFunction

Comment: aside: in python3 you can loop the list with `for i in self.data['big_list']:`

Comment: If you get the first name as a default, then you will only do one iteration of the for loop, so it won't be that inefficient.

Comment: Further, from the amount of code you've shown us, my immediate instinct is that the way to improve it would be to have data that is organized in a better way, but without knowing your data model and use case, there's not much help to provide.

Comment: It's a json file external to my program. Something like this: https://github.com/ethereum-lists/chains/blob/master/_data/chains/eip155-1.json

Answer (score 2):

if think there is a general bad practice or misunderstanding of class: there is a class right? and you check if your instance has the same name of one of the names in your list, and set itself.

-> in your instance it seems you have large data, containing a list of people AND attributes for one person. That does not sound correct.

Let say the class is called Person.

- you can create an **init**() method, which takes one row of your data['big_list']. instead of setting each attribute in a loop.
- you might also want to create a **equals()** method which checks if a person is the same as someone else. (check duplicates)
- consider taking your large_data out of that class.

Could you provide us with a little more context?

Comment: Ignore the class part please, I'm checking in an imported json file for a name and use save the data relateed to that name in the class (name, address, etc).
The json is not mine, it's a standard one and I can't modify.

I'd rather simplify the code than add context, I think it'll get confusing rather than simpler. Please ignore the class part, if it would be a simple function, it's very innefficient to do this:

Answer (score 1):

Here are some comments (that might be insuficient because I do not really understand what you want to achieve with the program).

The purpose of the `for` loop seems to be to find an item of the list `self.data['big_list']`  that meets the condition `self.data['big_list'][i]['name'] == name`, get some data and then terminate. Each entry of `self.data['big_list']` is a `dict`.

This is a good job for a technique called *list comprehension*, which is much faster than for-looping.

The expression

```
filtered = [item for item in self.data['big_list'][1:] if item['name'] == name]
```

results in a list of dicts that are not the first one and meet the name-condition. The used expression `self.data['big_list'][1:]` is all of `self.data['big_list']` but the first one. This technique is called `slicing` of lists. I assume you are not interested in the first entry, because you got the `name` from this first entry and search for other entries with the same name (which your for-loop doesn't, btw).

There may be more than one entry in `filtered`, or, none. I assume you are only interested in the first match, because your program does `return` when a match happens. Therefore, the second part of the program would be

```
if len(filtered) > 0:
    first_match = filtered[0]
    self.name = name
    self.address = first_match['address']
    ...
```

This way the structure of the program is more clear and other readers can better understand what the program does. Furthermore, it is much faster ;-).